# How to *overlay* sibling divs that are centered inside a flexbox, without using absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[See this plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/mvFGfrne3LnVlYsXyDRc?p=preview) What is the most efficient way to do this using css flexbox, without resorting to absolute positioning?

Current plunker code is as follows:

CSS

```
 .container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border:4px dashed red;
  height:600px;
  width:80%;
}

.under{
  background-color:yellow;
  height:80% !important;
  width:40% !important;
}

.over{
  background-color:blue;
  height:50%;
  width:20%;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class='container'>
  <div class='under'> Under - this should be in the center of the container </div>
   <div class='over'>
    <h3>Center overlay the blue div on top of the green!</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: you can't do that using flexbox, since the logic behind flexbox model is not meant for this kind of positioning . Explain why you don't want to use absolute positioning?

Comment: @easwee, Because absolute positioning is not inherently responsive.

Comment: Why can't you make "over" a child of "under"?

Answer (score 0):

for 
.over
add     margin-left: -100px; to make them overlay...but I don't know why you want this...